# How to make changes to mern app deployed on heroku and how to check the changes before I deploy it in production?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, heroku, mern

Let me explain further, what i mean is i have created a mern app which is already deployed on heroku now i want to make changes in the app but before i push it again on heroku i want to check my changes locally so how do i do that?
I tried the heroku local command but it starts the client side and cannot fetch the node server routes please help me out here !? here is my code:

node app.js

```
import express from "express";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";       
import dotenv from 'dotenv'
import router from './Routes/auth.js'
import path from 'path';

dotenv.config({path:'./config.env'});

const host = '0.0.0.0';
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const app= express()
app.use(router);

if(process.env.NODE_ENV === "production"){
    const __dirname=path.resolve();
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,"/client/build")));
    app.get("*",(req,res)=>{
        res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname,'client','build','index.html'));
    })
}

app.listen(port,host,()=>{
    console.log(`Server Started Succesfully on port number ${port}`);
})
```

package.jso(nodejs)

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "npx nodemon app.js",
    "client":"npm start --prefix client",
    "dev":"concurrently \"npm start\" \"npm run client\"",
    "heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.1",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.6",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.2",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "mongoose": "^6.1.8"
  }
}
```

[My file system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wdr9r.png)

Comment: I'm not sure it's clear what you're asking really. If you're talking about making changes then viewing them immediately, I think you just need to run npm run start.

You have to open a new terminal in your app.js directory, then type npm run start.

Comment: @LuddensDesir I think you got the point i was trying to make , but this is what i have been trying for quite sometime now. what is happening is the client runs successfully but when i (for eg) try to login nothing happens so i check the logs which states "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)" So what can i do here 
P.s works fine on the deployed website and was working fine b4 deployment

Comment: @LuddensDesir the Server also starts successfully i.e iam running the node.js server too

Comment: Oh. I think it's probably because your process.node.ENV is set to production when you're running on your local machine. It's either not set on your local machine or you're in "development" like I always have it typed out on my local machines. 

You can use dotenv to set up your environment variables, I think local to the app. To do it globally on windows 10 just press the start button, and press env. "System Properties" will come up. Click "Environment Varibales" I ususally add NODE_ENV = development to both the user and the system.

Comment: @LuddensDesir Nope no luck still the same thing

Comment: @LuddensDesir thx for the help!! got the solution had to add proxy in my react package.json one last question if i make changes, it wont effect the production until i push changes right ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. You see changes remotely after you push. I thought this wasn't a react app since I don't see the dependency. You just included it in the html huh? The easiest way to set up react is npm installing it then configuring a proxy with webpack. Webpack sounds more complex than it s but you literally just have to read the documentation and it's simple. :D

Comment: haha ikr anyway thx again for the help !

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

According to my testing You can do:

1. Check on Browser Tools: Like Responsiveness
2. Check your elements in DevTools
3. All Pages all Div tags elements, responsiveness of app, and design you can check of your app
4. for node server routes you can check by testing it in Postman API tool
5. That's it Ready to Deploy

Comment: Thx, But what iam asking is, After deploying the website to heroku how do i make changes and test it locally b4 re depolying it again